# XML Schema for Sitemap binding it together

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd, sitemap

I have the following code for defining XML Schema. Having a problem in keeping the lines together. Worked fine before.

```
public static FileContentResult WriteTo(SiteMapFeed feedToFormat)
{
    var siteMap = feedToFormat;          

    //TODO: DO something, next codes are just DEMO
    var header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
        + Environment.NewLine + "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\""
        + Environment.NewLine + "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\""
        + Environment.NewLine + "xsi:schemaLocation=\""
        + Environment.NewLine + "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        + Environment.NewLine + "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd\">";

    var urls = new System.Text.StringBuilder();        
    foreach (var site in siteMap.Items) 
    {
        urls.Append(string.Format("<url><loc>http://www.{0}/</loc><lastmod>{1}</lastmod><changefreq>{2}</changefreq><priority>{3}</priority></url>", site.Url, site.LastMod, site.ChangeFreq, site.Priority));

    }                    
    byte[] fileContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header + urls + "</urlset>");
    return new FileContentResult(fileContent, "text/xml");
}
```

SO this is now causing the following error:

[image]

Where am I doing it wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in that "xsi:schemaLocation" bit I think - you can't have multiple lines between quotes in an XML attribute, if my brain remembers correctly. Try changing to:

```
var header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    + Environment.NewLine + "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\""
    + Environment.NewLine + "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\""
    + Environment.NewLine + "xsi:schemaLocation=\""
    + "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd\">" + Environment.NewLine;
```